# How to get Recent Activity using Graph API or FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get Recent Activity using Graph API or FQL ? I'm talking about information that is available at this location: http://www.facebook.com/vanityname/allactivity?filter_onlyme=on

I coulnd't find anything in FB API documentation (not surprisingly). Scraping it from the web-site looks complicated as well because it's fetched by calling http://www.facebook.com/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/TimelineProfileAllActivityPagelet which returns very hard to parse content.

In case you guys wondering FQL that I tried is `select post_id,actor_id,created_time,message,description,xid from stream where source_id = me()`

Comment: Your query returns data that is about as close as I would expect to Facebook function you reference. What aren't you getting that you expect?

Comment: @cpilko it just doesn't return some comments I made in other people's posts.

Comment: You may not get them depending on that user's privacy settings. Read this for an explanation: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: Did you find a solution / workaround to this? I'm in the same situation: I can see one of my own comments when I call friendsusername/feed, but it does not appear in myusername/posts.

There must be a better way of doing it than calling friend/feed for each friend?

Comment: @Crashthatch Nope, I didn't find anything. FP API is still crap :) Please post answer below if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this information in the API. In addition there is no documentation listed for this either at https://developers.facebook.com